# Json_encoding a Php Variable in an Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Currently I am using a jQuery Ajax asynchronous function to request a PHP page multiple times until a large number of spreadsheet rows are processed. Right now I am using the following code to set the variables to be passed to the requested page, I am not sure if this is the proper way to do it or not. PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $new_spreadsheet = nl2br($_POST['spreadsheet']);
    $new_spreadsheet = explode('<br />', $new_spreadsheet);
    array_shift($new_spreadsheet);
    $new_spreadsheet = array_values($new_spreadsheet);
    $new_spreadsheet = json_encode($new_spreadsheet);
    echo var_dump($new_spreadsheet);
}
```

JavaScript/PHP:

```
var done = false,
offset = 0,
limit = 20,
rankings_abv_twenty = 0,
sum = 0,
num_count = 0,
websites = 1
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo ', spreadsheet = '.$new_spreadsheet;
}?>;
```

On the requested PHP page (which happens to be Object-Oriented PHP), I have the following code to slice off 20 rows to process on the given request. Please not the PHP is a full working class, I just did not include all the PHP for the sake of post length. Also note, I have another page which calls the class, which passes the spreadsheet variable to the constructor of the PHP by reference as $_POST['spreadsheet'], so I know I have the right value as the spreadsheet. PHP:

```
$this->offset = $offset;
$this->limit = $limit;
$this->spreadsheet = json_decode($spreadsheet);
```

Here is the PHP line which slices off the rows:

```
$this->rows = array_slice($this->spreadsheet, $this->offset, $this->limit);
```

For some reason my code is not working properly and is giving me the following errors relating to the above code:

```
PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
PHP Warning:  array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

I think it might have something to do with how my string is getting passed the requested PHP. Also, just as a further note, when I use var_dump() on my spreadsheet variable before it is passed to the requested PHP, I get it outputted as a string like so:

```
string(7560) "String content goes here"
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first look, instead of echoing the json_encode, you used var_dump.

And when manually modifying the json encoded string make sure to use " around the vars.

And this:

```
  websites = 1
  <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo ', spreadsheet = '.$new_spreadsheet;
   }?>;
```

Will result in:

```
  websites = 1, spreadsheet = "{"1":"foo","2":"bar","3":"baz","4":"blong"}";
```

Wrap the line in ' if that's what you expect it..

like this:

```
 echo ", spreadsheet = '".$new_spreadsheet."'";
```

Comment: Could you further explain what you mean by the second sentence?

Comment: You used echo ', spreadsheet = '.$new_spreadsheet;

If you used it to create a json_encoded string, replace with "spreadsheet"

Comment: Double check what you echo since the json_decode is complaining about an array instead of string.

Comment: When I put quotes around it I get a different error, which my jQuery outputs: "Error: parsererror".

Comment: I have already done a whole lot of testing as far as variable types and such go, it's not like I just didn't do anything and posted a random question. I've looked up a lot online and as far as the page I am starting the request on the variable seems to be a string with the correct values.

Comment: Obviously the json_decode() is not receiving a valid string, can you provide an example of the json_encoded string ?

Comment: The output of my code is: ["Part Number (With Link)\tGoogle Link\tRanking\tWebsite\tPDF\tDate","\r\n140 XTS 002 00\t140 XTS 002 00\t4\tmy_website.com\tNo\t8\/5\/2014"]

Comment: That's why is considered an array, because is not wrapped as string between '' , [a,b,c] = array.

Comment: I've wrapped it in a string, and it still does not work. I've used some PHP to get around my problem for now, it is taking me too much time to do it the "correct" way. I think it has a different problem besides the string encapsulation.